# Outlook Express emails disappeared - can I get them back?

Tags: windows

A user opens his Outlook Express 6 (all windows updates up to date) this morning and finds that his inbox is empty.  200-odd messages that were there yesterday have disappeared.  I have checked that the View is set to All Messages, and it is.  No rules in existence.  New emails arriving are adding to the inbox.  Other folders (sent, deleted) have the same content as yesterday.

It seems to be the files related to the inbox had a problem, or physically got deleted, and OE6 just self-recovered by giving the user an inbox with nothing in it.

Is there anything I can do, other than scanning hard disk sectors for text, that may retrieve these lost emails?

Thanks.

Comment: If Outlook Express is configured to access a remote mailbox using IMAP then a likely cause of this is someone connecting to the same mailbox using POP and downloading (and deleting) all messages in INBOX (since that's all POP can access). This is likely to be through an action on the user's part (since it needs their password). Looking at mail server logs may shed light (and lead you to the POP client that has the downloaded messages).

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is, restore from backup.

Then upgrade to something developed more recently than a decade and a half ago and is still supported with the likes of ongoing security patches from the vendor.